# How to fix ("monomds" not resolved) error in vegan. problem using metaMDS() function

Tags: fortran, vegan

I'm trying to run a NMDS using the metaMDS() function, to investigate differences in species composition of butterflies. However I am getting the error:

"Error in .Fortran("monoMDS", nobj = as.integer(nobj), nfix = as.integer(0),  : "monomds" not resolved from current namespace (vegan)"

Please could you help me resolve it?!

I'm using a species composition matrix with rows as sites and columns as species, filled with no. of butterflies.

I've updated RStudio and all the relevant packages.

nmds <- metaMDS(site.matrix, k=3, trymax = 5000)

Error in .Fortran("monoMDS", nobj = as.integer(nobj), nfix = as.integer(0),  : 
  "monomds" not resolved from current namespace (vegan)

Comment: I think you'll have to be a lot more explicit about both the code you are working with and the problem(s) you are having.  Read the material in the help centre, especially those parts which describe a [mcve] and its importance.

Comment: This is odd. If you have installed **vegan** in standard way, it has passed tests for your platform and should work. There is an issue with uppercase and lowercase letters, but calling FORTRAN routines should be ignorant of case. Have you really installed **vegan** with standard procedures?

Comment: I installed vegan using standard procedures. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling it too, but unfortunately no success